# How to make this exception for a rewrite rule

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, http-redirect

I have the following web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/reset-password/*" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/index.html?utm_source={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The problem is even though I defined an exception for the `/reset-password` URL the redirect is still being made on that URL... As the rule name states my frontend is an Angular app with its own routing, but I need to have some rewriting functionality on any URL BUT the `/reset-password/tokenhere`

Comment: The pattern is wrong. Enable FRT and you will see that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules#:~:text=%20Using%20Failed%20Request%20Tracing%20to%20Trace%20Rewrite,rule%20has%20been%20created%2C%20make%20a...%20More%20

Comment: @LexLi how is it supposed to be then?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the below condition if you want to match /reset-password/tokenhere :

```
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/reset-password/(.*)" negate="true" />
```

if you just want to match /reset-password then use this:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/reset-password/$" negate="true" />
```

Comment: It redirects me to `index.html` like below for some reason, even though it's supposed not to. Any clue how to fix this? And yes, at least the pattern works now, but I can't access that path (/reset-password/tokenhere) on my Angular App now...

Comment: @Munchkin please try to clear your history and access the site again.

Comment: it didn't help :/ neither using incognito/privacy mode did...

Comment: @Munchkin could you please share your failed request tracing snapshot?

Comment: How do I save it?

Comment: if you meant this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85 then it's done but how can I securely transfer these files to you? The files are too large to put here. Or maybe I did a trace which is not exactly what you asked for so I would be really happy if you could clarify.

Comment: @Munchkin you could share the screenshot of the tracing log of URL rewrite. like this: [image](https://i.imgur.com/yRiC2pp.png)

Comment: [there you go](https://imgur.com/a/Ul4Tyau). the blurred out URL is just the IP of the server (index page)

Comment: @Munchkin make sure you enable the url rewrite tracing. in your image i can not see any log about URL rerwite.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: there's no such option to select "Rewrite" in the selection, so I just went with Security. the only other not visible option is WebSocket https://imgur.com/a/kzgsauJ

Comment: @Munchkin again try to install the failed request tracing in iis.

Comment: Here's the log with the rewrites https://imgur.com/sISXeiI

Comment: @Munchkin Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222649/discussion-between-jalpa-panchal-and-munchkin).

Comment: if I were to give out a bounty, would that incentivize you to answer the question?

Comment: you could try to create a new site and add the rule which I mentioned. disbale all the rules from the server level.

Comment: That's apparently not really an option for me, since it needs to be the default site and it wouldn't change much...

Comment: @Munchkin then you can try to disable other rule and enable the rule which is causing the issue and troubleshoot it by using the failed request tracing rule.

Comment: I have already disabled all the rules in the IIS Manager and left only the web.config file config take effect and the result is the same..